# Hi, I'm a beginner in Python, and I would like to know how to get an index number from a list with multiple values in the same index

Tags: python-3.x

Ex:
my_list=[['Krishna', '67', '68', '69'], ['Arjun', '70', '98', '63'], ['Malika', '52', '56', '60']]

query_name=input() #The user will insert the name that he wants to know the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a simple comparison:

```
my_list=[['Krishna', '67', '68', '69'], ['Arjun', '70', '98', '63'], ['Malika', '52', '56', '60']]

query_name=input("Enter name ")

for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    if value[0] == query_name:
        print(f"Found {query_name} at position {index}")
        break

# Enter name 
# > Arjun
# Found Arjun at position 1
```

Comment: Thanks Bro.  :-)